# Bound on the number of primitive divisors of the $n$th Fibonacci number

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors, recurrences

It is a result of Carmichael that for any integer $n > 12$, the Fibonacci number $F_n$ has at least one primitive divisor, that is, a prime factor $p$ such that $p$ does not divide any $F_m$ with $1 \leq m < n$. Indeed, a more general result for all Lucas and Lehmer sequences has been proven by Bilu, Hanrot, and Voutier [1].

But my question is: **What about an upper bound for the number of primitive divisors of $F_n$?**

If $p$ is a primitive divisor of $F_n$, then it is known that $p \equiv \pm 1 \bmod n$, hence $p \geq n - 1$. Thus, if $P_n$ is the number of primitive divisors of $F_n$, we have

$$(n - 1)^{P_n} \leq \prod_{p \text{ prim. div. of } F_n} p \mid F_n \leq \alpha^{n-1} ,$$

where $\alpha := (1 + \sqrt{5})/2$, and consequently

$$P_n \leq \frac{(n - 1)\log \alpha}{\log (n - 1)} .$$

Is some better upper bound known?

[1] Bilu, Hanrot, and Voutier, *Existence of primitive divisors of Lucas and Lehmer numbers*, Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik (Crelles Journal), 2001(539), pp. 75-122.

Comment: You can get a tiny improvement by noting that if $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ are the primitive divisors in increasing order, then first (as you note) $p_1\ge n-1$, and then $p_2\ge p_1+2=n+1$, etc. So $(n-1)(n+1)\cdots(n+2k-3)\le\alpha^{n-1}$.

Comment: @JoeSilverman, do we know that primitive divisors occur with low multiplicity? Otherwise a large prime power could be a factor. On a brighter note, Granville showed that for some sequences, primitive divisors occur to an odd power for n not too small.  Gerhard "Can't Be Good Without Bad" Paseman, 2017.04.21.

Comment: Also, if n itself has a small prime factor k, then you can reduce the exponent (n-1) by subtracting something near n/k.  This is significant for n which are not coprime to 6.  (Maybe even replace the right hand side by $\alpha^{\phi(n)}$.) Gerhard "Use Primitive Facts For Optimization" Paseman, 2017.04.21.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman As far as I know, there are no significant theorems saying that most primitive divisors appear with low multiplicity, although in practice that's surely the case. I think that in general, for questions of this sort, it's best to first consider the simpler case of the sequence $2^n-1$, or $A^n-1$. And just the fact we don't know that $2^p-1\not\equiv0\pmod{p^2}$ for infinitely many primes indicates our lack of understanding for these sorts of questions. The OP might have better luck with an average question, i.e., bound growth of $\sum_{n<X}P_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A known bound for the average $\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}P_n$ is
$$
\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log x}{x^2} \sum_{n\leq x}P_n
\leq
\frac{3}{2 \pi^2} \log \alpha.
$$
This is not much better than the above point-wise bound.
Making progress on this average seems to be hard. One could try to get some sort of prime number theorem
$$
\sum_{n\leq x}P_n \sim \,\,\,?
$$
The main obstacle here seems to be that all proofs of the prime number theorem (at least the ones I know) somehow rely on 
$$
\sum_{p\leq x}\log p \sim \sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda(n) 
$$
with $\Lambda$ denoting the von Mangoldt function. In our situation we can determine the asymptotic behavior of the following sums
$$
\sum_{p: p|F_i \text{ for some } i\leq x} e_p\log p
 \sim 
\sum_{n: n|F_i \text{ for some } i\leq x} \Lambda(n) 
$$
where the sums are taken over (prime) divisors of Fibonacci numbers and $e_p$ denotes the largest exponent such that whenever $p|F_i\Rightarrow p^{e_p}|F_i$. The hard part is now, to relate this asymptotic behavior to that of
 $$
\sum_{p: p|F_i \text{ for some } i\leq x} \log p
$$
a weighted version of  the sum we are interested in.  It is not clear how this can be done.
For the averages of this weighted version it is known that
$$
\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \sum_{p|F_i\text{ for some } i\leq x} \log p 
\leq
\frac{3}{ \pi^2} \log \alpha.
$$
We also know that any improvement on the constant here would imply the existence of infinitely many Wall-Sun-Sun primes. It is an open problem whether  such primes exist. However, since partial summation works differently here, the relation of the weighted average to the average is not obvious.

Comment: Thanks. Would you kindly give me the reference of the first result?

Comment: Sure. E.g. Thm. 7 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.01715).